# „Danke“ als Antwort auf eine Ja-Nein-Frage

Tags: usage, question

Auf eine Entscheidungsfrage wie »Möchten Sie etwas trinken?« antworten manche Leute mit »Danke.« oder »Danke, danke.«.

Heißt das immer *nein*, also die Person möchte nichts trinken? Wäre das in diesem Fall also eine Kurzform von »Nein, danke.«?

Eine solche Antwort verunsichert mich meistens, oft frage ich nach. Ich könnte mir genauso gut vorstellen, dass es eine Kurzfrom von »Danke, dass Sie endlich fragen!« oder »Danke für dieses Angebot, das nehme ich gerne an.« sein könnte.

Comment: Ich kann es so betonen, das es sowohl ablehnend als auch bejahend sein kann. Von daher: Tonfall, Mimik und meistens eine zugehörige Handgeste entscheiden in diesem Fall.

Comment: @nixda Was willst du denn in dem Satz „Danke.“ betonen? Da hast du theoretisch 2 Möglichkeiten für die betonte Silbe und 4 Möglichkeiten für die Länge der Silben. Praktisch reduziert es sich darauf, ob du die erste Silbe lang oder kurz aussprichst. Beides liefert keinen Hinweis auf die gestellt Frage.

Comment: @Toscho Danke, natürlich kann man "Danke" verschieden betonen. Da gäbe es das herablassende Danke, dass einem Nein gleich käme, das ironische Danke, dass auch Nein bedeuten würde. Oder ein freudiges Danke, das ein Ja bedeuten würde. Und noch einige mehr, aber der Kommentar wird sonst zu lang. Die Feinheiten der deutschen Sprache lassen vieles zu. Es kommt einzig auf die Redegewandtheit des Sprechers an.

Comment: @nixda Siehe http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_%28Phonetik%29

Comment: Ich meine auch, dass die Stimme verraten kann, was man will. Eine Ablehnung wäre bei mir mit dunkler Stimme, eine Bejahung mit heller gesprochen. Dazu muss der Hörer freilich meine Normalstimme kennen. :)

Comment: Wenn ich den Dialog (»Möchten Sie etwas trinken?« - »Danke.«) nur lese und sonst keine Informationen habe, hätte ich eher angenommen, dass die zweite Person sich für das Angebot bedankt und es annimmt. Aber es stimmt: Die Antwort ist alles andere als eindeutig, und ich persönlich halte es für eine Unsitte nur mit »Danke« zu antworten.

Comment: Wirklich interessant. Ich hatte heute genau die Situation, dass ich von einem US-Amerikaner in sehr gutem Deutsch gefragt wurde, ob ich ein Glas Wasser möchte, worauf ich mit "Danke!" antwortete. Für mich bedeutete das selbstredend "Nein, danke!", dennoch goss er ein Glas Wasser ein, das ich aber nicht anfasste, weil ich mir nicht sicher war, ob er sich oder mir dieses Glas eingoss. Ich vermute einfach mal, dass ein einfaches "Thank you" in der entsprechenden Situation im Englischen soviel wie "Ja, gerne!" bedeutet hätte. Kulturelle Unterschiede eben.

Answer (score 10):

Wie in einem Kommentar angemerkt, spielen hier noch einige weitere Faktoren mit. Das "Nein" wird in solchen Fällen üblicherweise mit Kopfschütteln oder durch eine 'abweisende' Handbewegung signalisiert. Auch der Gesichtsausdruck vermittelt häufig ein "Nein".

Ein "Danke, dass Sie endlich fragen" wäre nicht angebracht. Das wäre aufs äußerste höhnisch. Außerdem, wenn man erwartet, dass man etwas zu trinken angeboten bekäme, könnte man ja auch einfach mal sich melden. Natürlich könnte es aber ein "Danke, dass Sie mir etwas anbieten sein". 
Der Punkt ist aber: Möchte man etwas trinken, sollte man ja auch sagen, was man möchte. Nochmal darauf zu warten, dass nachgefragt wird, welcher Drink es denn sein soll, wäre mindestens merkwürdig.

Deswegen achte auf die Gesichtsausdrücke, Kopf- und Handbewegung, wenn nur ein kurzes "Danke" kommt. Die signalisieren die Intention. Und in aller Regel ist ein bloßes "Danke" immer "Nein".

Im Falle eines "Ja", würde man automatisch das gewünschte Getränk nennen, oder nachfragen, was denn angeboten wird. In jedem Fall fände ich es aber komisch sowas zu hören:

> Danke. Eine Cola bitte.

Lange Rede, kurzer Sinn:

Ein bloßes "Danke" ist (im gegebenen Kontext) fast immer ein "Nein" und wird meistens durch Körpersprache signalisiert. Ist es mal nicht "Nein", sollte es in der gegebenen Situation offensichtlich sein.

Comment: Klingt logisch, aber überzeugt mich nicht ganz. Die Alternativen Bedeutungen von „Danke.“ sind einfach zu vielfältig, als dass man hier Annahmen tätigen könnte. Auf jeden Fall nachfragen.

Comment: Ich bin neu hier und habe eine Verständnisfrage: Ist es üblich, dass man hier nicht nur sprachbezogen, sondern wie in diesem Fall auch soziologisch auf eine Frage antwortet, wenn dies nicht sprachimmanent ist?

Comment: @Polyhistor Ich weiß zwar nicht was "immanant" bedeutet... Aber im Bezug auf die Frage muss man halt mal etwas weiter ausholen. Das Wort "Danke" allein hat nämlich keine weitere Konnotation, als das was es halt eigentlich ausdrückt.

Comment: »Im Falle eines "Ja", würde man automatisch das gewünschte Getränk nennen« - Das hängt doch von der Fragestellung ab! „Kann ich Ihnen einen Kaffee anbieten?“ - „Danke!” „Möchtest Du ein Glas Wasser?“ - „Danke!“ ... Nicht zu erwähnen all die anderen Entscheidungsfragen, die mit Trinken überhaupt nichts zu tun haben, aber trotzdem mit „Danke“ beantwortet werden können...

Answer (score 5):

Die Antwort hat auch eine regionale Komponente. In Süddeutschland und in Teilen der Schweiz (Österreich weiss ich nicht), kann nur "Danke" auch ja bedeuten.

Eine beispielhafte Gesprächssituation: An einem Tisch mit mehreren Personen unterhalten sich A und B. Eine dritte Person C spricht A an: "Kaffee?".  A könnte hier antworten "Danke" und sofort die Unterhaltung mit B fortsetzen.  Damit wäre dann "Ja" gemeint und der Dank für das (noch folgende) Einschenken gleich mit abgedeckt.

Zusammengenommen würde ich sagen, die Antwort auf die Frage ist immer situationsabhängig und kann sehr subtil von der Mimik und Gestik abhängen.

Answer (score 2):

Wer über ein ausgeprägtes Sprachverständnis/-gefühl verfügt, kann einem "Danke!" ein "Nein." entnehmen, denn es heißt korrekterweise "Nein, danke!" und "Ja, bitte!"

Allerdings verlasse ich mich nicht darauf, dass ein derart Sprechfauler es mit dieser Absicht formuliert und werde in einer solchen Situation auch künftig nachfragen.

Comment: Wie du selbst es tust, sollte man sich nicht darauf verlassen. In Umgebungen, in den hohe Register zu erwarten sind, sollte man auch ein komplettes „Nein, danke.“ erwarten und folglich selbiges nicht in ein „Danke.“ hineininterpretieren. In anderen Umgebungen kann das „Danke.“ so ziemlich alles bedeuten.

Comment: Wieso sollte denn „Ja. Danke!“ unkorrekt sein? Mein „Ja“ ist abgeschlossen und ich schiebe noch ein „Danke“ hinterher, weil ich nett bin. Gleichzeitig bin ich aber wortfaul, und lasse deshalb das „Ja“ weg, nicke dafür aber freundlich... Abgesehen davon, dass es Unmengen von Menschen ohne ausgeprägtes Sprachgefühl gibt, die einfach so Deutsch sprechen, ohne sich dabei um korrekt/inkorrekt zu scheren :)

Comment: Wie ich bereits in einem Kommentar erwähnte, hat das etwas mit der Etikette zu tun (nicht mit der Grammatik). Wer weder Etikette, noch grammatikalische Regeln lernen will, kann sein Sprachgefühl durch das Lesen klassischer Literatur bilden. Deinen letzten Satz kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Willst du damit sagen, dass der willkürliche Sprachgebrauch der Menge richtiges Deutsch überflüssig mache?

Answer (score 1):

If uttered with any kind of enthusiasm or surprise, it means "yes".  So "Oh danke" will mean "yes".  If it's in any form incomplete, it means "no", like in reply to "Kann ich Ihnen etwas zu trinken anbieten?": "Danke" on its own is supposed to complete the interaction, so if you don't say what you want, it is expected that you want nothing.

The polite form of "Danke" will tend to be followed by an explanation or qualification, like "Danke, gerne." (which implies that you would appreciate it though you could not demand it), or "Danke, ich habe schon gegessen." (which explains why you choose to decline).

For things like a job interview, the proper thing if you don't want anything to drink is to accept a glass of water and just sip very little from it: otherwise the host will ask every 10 minutes again.

Answer (score 0):

Hier würde ich immer auf Nummer sicher gehen und nachfragen. „Danke.“ kann vieles meinen, gerade eben weil es keine sinnvolle Antwort auf die Frage ist und auch nicht das standardisierte „Nein, danke.“ ist.

Körpersprache kann einen Hinweis geben, muss sie aber nicht.